# link external mysql database with flash AS3

Tags: mysql, database, actionscript-3

how to link external mysql database with flash AS3 ??

this is like I want:

my Database on server :

```
Database
username : x, pass: y
```

my flash on my users computers

```
login
your username :
your password :
```

Answer (score 0):

To integrate MySQL database content into your Flash movies you have to create server side middleware (in PHP for example) which will communicate with your flash using HTTP protocol: ajax, xml etc.

Comment: @user1219141 like that http://library.creativecow.net/articles/brimelow_lee/php_mysql.php

Comment: I now that, my problem is on the remoting :(